# How to get Software Update to automatically grab kernel source along with kernel update?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10. For some reason, every time there's a kernel update, it does not install the `linux-headers-*` and `linux-header-*-generic` into `/usr/src` anymore. So every time I update my virtual Ubuntu in VirtualBox, I have to manually install the kernel headers before running the Guest Additions package again.

I'm pretty sure 12.04 automatically installed kernel headers because I never had to do that before. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure the `linux-headers-generic` metapackage is installed. It depends on the latest available version of the headers, and will pull in the packages you've mentioned automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply invoke:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```