# How can I ensure the linux-headers-x.xx.x-xx package is automatically installed when the kernel is upgraded?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, unattended-upgrades, linux-headers

Every few weeks/months the kernel on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 (x86_64) installation is automatically updated. That's fine, except that the corresponding kernel headers are not automatically installed at the same time and so the VirtualBox kernel modules are not rebuilt automatically. I have to manually do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

in order to trigger the rebuild. (I got that command from the answer to: [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue#220778))

How can I arrange for the linux headers to be automatically updated as well? Or, alternatively, how can I ensure that the VirtualBox modules are automatically rebuilt when the kernel is upgraded?

I have the linux-headers-generic package installed as suggested in the answer to [How to get Software Update to automatically grab kernel source along with kernel update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261292/how-to-get-software-update-to-automatically-grab-kernel-source-along-with-kernel?rq=1):

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.96.101).
linux-headers-generic set to manually installed.
```

Edited to add: The output of uname -a is

```
Linux riemann 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please add output of `uname -a` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the meta `linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04` is not installed.

The `linux-headers-generic` is installing headers for the 4.4 kernel, but you are using a HWE kernel, like 4.10.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and you should get headers updates.

Comment: Thanks - that package certainly wasn't installed, so I've installed it now. I'll wait until the next automated kernel upgrade happens to check that this has fixed it before I accept this answer. Fingers crossed...

Comment: Worked a treat - I just rebooted and have a new kernel (4.10.0-37-generic) and virtualbox still started without any manual intervention. Thanks!